# Asp.net mvc html melper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Ive got this function  as a html helper which should write a javascript function onto the page, I then call this in the masterpage like this <%Html.RenderBaseUrlScript(); %>

My problem is that the script never seems to be written to the page, I search in the source and cannot see it anywhere, I have tried moving this around from the head to the body of the html masterpage, Im really confused as to why this is not workung, please help
 public static string RenderBaseUrlScript(this HtmlHelper helper)
        {

```
        return string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'> $.url=function(url){{return '{0}'+url;}}", GetBaseUri());


    }
```

Comment: Perhaps a 'helper', rather than a 'melper'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<%= Html.RenderBaseUrlScript() %>
```

Notice the = sign and no semicolon.  Since your html helper method is not writing anything directly to the response stream (which is good), you need to actually call `Response.Write()` on the output of your function.  The `<%= %>` tags are short form for `Response.Write()`.

If your helper method was writing directly to the response stream itself, your code would be working.  But it's much better to have it this way.